# How to Convert File size to only Megabytes using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to take a file and only display it in megabytes. So for example, if I were to have a file that is only 120kb or 2mb, I want it to echo it out as 0.12mb and 2mb respectively.

Below is the code that I currently have and hoping if someone can help?

```
<?php
    function byte_convert($size) {
      # size smaller then 1kb
      if ($size < 1024) return $size . ' Byte';
      # size smaller then 1mb
      if ($size < 1048576) return sprintf("%4.2f KB", $size/1024);
      # size smaller then 1gb
      if ($size < 1073741824) return sprintf("%4.2f MB", $size/1048576);
      # size smaller then 1tb
      if ($size < 1099511627776) return sprintf("%4.2f GB", $size/1073741824);
      # size larger then 1tb
      else return sprintf("%4.2f TB", $size/1073741824);
    }


    $file_path = "pic1.jpg";

    $file_size = byte_convert(filesize($file_path));

    echo $file_size;

    ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: a Megabyte (MB) is 10^6 (1 000 000) bytes, a Mebibyte (MiB) is 2^20 (1 048 576) bytes. Do me a favor and use MiB, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just divide by 1024*1024

```
<?php
function get_mb($size) {
    return sprintf("%4.2f MB", $size/1048576);
}


$file_path = "pic1.jpg";

$file_size = get_mb(filesize($file_path));

echo $file_size;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is mate:

```
<?php
    function convert_to_mb($size)
    {
        $mb_size = $size / 1048576;
        $format_size = number_format($mb_size, 2) . ' MB';
        return $format_size;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function sizeFormat($bytes, $unit = "", $decimals = 2) {
    $units = array('B' => 0, 'KB' => 1, 'MB' => 2, 'GB' => 3, 'TB' => 4, 'PB' => 5, 'EB' => 6, 'ZB' => 7, 'YB' => 8);

    $value = 0;
    if ($bytes > 0) {
        if (!array_key_exists($unit, $units)) {
            $pow = floor(log($bytes)/log(1024));
            $unit = array_search($pow, $units);
        }
        $value = ($bytes/pow(1024,floor($units[$unit])));
    }
    if (!is_numeric($decimals) || $decimals < 0) {
        $decimals = 2;
    }
    return sprintf('%.' . $decimals . 'f '.$unit, $value);
}
```

With this function you can do what you want:

```
sizeFormat('120', 'MB');
```

Comment: Works great thank you and now I can simply do a one liner inside my echo statement like this `'. sizeFormat(filesize($dir . '/' . $file), 'MB') .'`